# VS Code imported python files not reflecting changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use VS Code to run both .py and .ipynb and it is connected to a git repo.

I have a file called analytics.py which are custom functions, and I'm using sandbox.ipynb to do some scripting.

After importing analytics.py using `from analytics import *`, I noticed there's a bug, which I then go fixed inside analytics.py.

However when I ran the import again, the error remains, and my changes is not reflected.

What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before. The notebook caches the import so you have to restart the kernel to import the changes.

Comment: Sadly even that doesn't work sometimes for me, and have to restart VS code.

Comment: Is there no workaround for this?